# Selecting rows based on a list of ALL (multiple) values in a comma delimited column using % before and after for fuzzy match

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql, split

Editing as requested.
I was able to get the data from a long string into a table so the question has changed to a degree.

My question is how do I get results returned based on a match of ALL values passed via a comma-delimited string?

I can, and have, used `STRING_SPLIT`. The problem I have is when using string split with `IN` or `INNER JOIN` or `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY`, a row is returned if any one (01)value in the passed string of values matches the value(s) in the column of the row; NOT ALL of the values in the string.

Again, the important point is that the rows returned need to match ON ALL values from the `STRING_SPLIT` of the values passed in the character string.

Also, as previously requested, here is a table example, a mocked-up piece of code and the expected results:

Code:

```
DECLARE @VALUES NVARCHAR(100) = 'X,G'

SELECT T5.COL1, T5.COL2, STRING_AGG(TRIM(TABLE1.COL3),', ') AS UNIQUE_STRING_OF_VALUES
FROM [SOME_DB].[dbo].[TABLE1] AS T5 
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@VALUES, ',') AS T10 ON T10.VALUE = T5.COL3

GROUP BY T5.COL1, T5.COL2
ORDER BY T5.COL1 ASC, T5.COL2 ASC
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to set up a [mcve]. Best provided as DDL and INSERT to set up appropriate 
 (minimal but sufficient) sample data to understand your issue and the expected output for this data. Add your own attempt and you will get help in minutes.

Comment: You say the column in Table_A.Column_A contains comma delimited data but then you post that you want a fuzzy match on thinks in that column like "1ABC-4C" ??? Which is it and can you post some data in a readily consumable format to help us help you?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm gonna have to ask you to [edit] your question to provide us [workable sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) end desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a built-in function that splits the strings:

```
declare
    @String             varchar(1000)   =   'This,is,a,test,search,function'
,   @SplitCharacter     varchar(10)     =   ','

select
*
from    string_split(@String,@SplitCharacter)
```

This splits the strings in this format:

[image: Results1]

Now when you alter the script like this, you can search for particular fields in the splits:

```
declare
    @String             varchar(1000)   =   'This,is,a,test,search,function'
,   @SplitCharacter     varchar(10)     =   ','

select
*
from    string_split(@String,@SplitCharacter)
where   Value like '%sea%'
```

This gives you the following results:

[image: Results2]

See [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7dfbd74830dfc3e6dad7b7b6254b31f8)

Let me know if this works...

Comment: Birel, thank-you for the response. I understand your answer and how it works but it seems my question was not clear enough. I edited my questions (as requested by a mod). The issue I am having is getting results that match on ALL of the values returned from a string_split, not just any one (01) of the values.

Comment: This is late (I was pulled off on a different project), but thank-you for the responses.

The final solution was to parse the character string of values out to a temp table for multiple searches by individual value(s).

Using String_Split in the WHERE clause in SQL does not appear to support selecting rows based on ALL VALUES but instead returns the row if any single value is a match.

Comment: Another solution is to use a cursor to look through every column, then return the expected results.

If you require this, I'll alter my answer to work like that. Please advise if still required @RScott?